# integration constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

for the problem

$$(1-2x)y'=y$$

the BC'S are $y(0)=-1$ and $y(1)=1$ and $0\leq x\leq 1$.

I solved this and got $\ln y =\ln\left(\dfrac 2 {1-2x}\right)+c$.

How do we determine the constant such that $y$ is real and finite everywhere from $0$ to $1$ (both limits included)?

Comment: Have you tried substituting $x = 0$ into the equation with $c$?

Comment: @GNUSupporterhe has two conditions but one constant

Answer (score 3):

Your equation is:
$$(1-2x)*\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{1-2x}$$
Integrating with respect to $x$:
$$\int\frac{1}{y}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\mathrm{d}x=\int\frac{1}{1-2x}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\log(y)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-2x)+C$$
$$\exp(\log(y))=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\log(1-2x)+C\right)$$
$$y=\exp(C)\exp\left(\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}\right)\right)$$
Redefining $C$:
$$y=\frac{C}{\sqrt{1-2x}}$$
From $y(0)=-1$:
$$-1=\frac{C_1}{\sqrt{1-2*0}}$$
$$C_1=-1$$
From $y(1)=1$
$$1=\frac{C_2}{\sqrt{1-2*1}}$$
$$C_2=\sqrt{-1}$$
So, for $y(1)=1$ the solution is $\frac{i}{\sqrt{1-2x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}$ (Thanks to [@Dylan](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/135643/dylan) for pointing my mistake out), and for $y(0)=-1$ the solution is $y=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}$
And also, for a first order differential eqaution you can give only $1$ initial condition unless "they are telling the same" (To get a continuous solution). But you can consider the function
$$y(x)=
\begin{cases}
    -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}& \text{for } x< \frac{1}{2}\\
    \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}              & \text{for } x>\frac{1}{2}
\end{cases}$$
This function satisfies the differential equation for all $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{\frac{1}{2}\right\}$, and it's continuous in it's domain.
Note: With using the absolute value you can avoid using complex numbers (and the mistakes they can cause) like [Dylan did in his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2644334/281471).

Comment: This is not quite true. For $x > 1/2$ the solution is $\ln y = -\frac12 \ln(2x-1) + K$, with a different constant

Comment: @Dylan The derivate of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}$ is $\frac{1}{(2x-1)^{3/2}}$. Multiplying it by $1-2x$ we get: $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}\neq-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}$

Comment: $y' = -\frac{1}{(2x-1)^{3/2}}$. Multiplying by $1-2x$ cancels the negative sign

Comment: $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})'=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$, but you need to use chain rule and multiply it by $(2x-1)'=2$.

Comment: Ok but the negative sign still goes away, which means $(2x-1)^{1/2}$ does satisfy the equation...

Comment: @Dylan You are right!

Comment: @Dylan The $C \notin \mathbb{R}$ is a good solution for $x>\frac{1}{2}$ then, since the $\sqrt{1-2x} \notin \mathbb{R}$ too, right (for $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$)? $\frac{i}{\sqrt{1-2x}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}$

Comment: Not quite. The solution is piecewise. See my answer.

Comment: @Dylan I've checked it. But what's the difference in $\frac{i}{\sqrt{1-2x}}$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}$?

Comment: I would prefer to stick with the real-valued coefficient if possible. The complex square root is ambiguous, unless you specify that it's the principal root, then they are the same.

Comment: @Dylan thank you, I've edited my answer. I hope it's better now.

Answer (score 2):

Let's go through the solution again. The equation separates to
$$ \frac{y'}{y} = \frac{1}{1-2x} $$

The equation in undefined on $y=0$ and $x=\frac12$. This means there are 4 possible regions in $\Bbb R^2$ where the solution can exist.

$$ \begin{cases} 
\ln y = -\frac12 \ln (1-2x) + c_1, && x < \frac12, \ y > 0 \\
\ln (-y) = -\frac12 \ln (1-2x) + c_2, && x < \frac12, \ y < 0 \\
\ln y = -\frac12\ln(2x-1) + c_3, && x > \frac12, \ y > 0 \\ 
\ln (-y) = -\frac12\ln(2x-1) + c_4, && x > \frac12, \ y < 0 
\end{cases} $$

If one is not looking for a specific solution that satisfies an initial condition, then you may write the general solution as
$$ \ln |y| = -\frac12\ln|1-2x| + C $$

or
$$ |y| = A |1-2x|^{-1/2} $$

That's the short answer for why we need absolute values when integrating the log function. The absolute values go away the moment an initial condition is assigned.

Back to our function. Your two initial conditions allow solutions in the second and third regions, respectively. The condition $y(0)=-1$ gives $c_2 = 0$. The condition $y(1)=1$ gives $c_3=0$. Putting it altogether and taking the exponential, we obtain the piecewise final solution

$$ y(x) = \begin{cases} -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2x}}, && x < \frac12 \\
\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2x-1}}, && x > \frac12 \end{cases} $$

---

As for your last question, there are no such solution (except $y \equiv 0$) that is finite on $(0,1)$, again due to the singular point.

Comment: @egreg For some reason, I can never spell "separate" correctly

Comment: That's where speaking a Romance language comes in handy. `;-)` By the way, this is an interesting case where English kept the position of the Latin tonic accent, whereas Italian moved it.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln y =\ln(2/(1-2x))+c\\
y =e^{\ln(2/(1-2x))+c}\\
y =e^{\ln(2/(1-2x))}e^{c}$

But $e^c$ is just as much of an arbitrary constant as $c$ was.

$y =Ce^{\ln(2/(1-2x))}\\
y =\frac {C}{1-2x}$

However, you have a problem at $x = \frac 12$

Going back to:

$(1-2x)y' = y \implies y(\frac 12) = 0$

And that is going to mean that $y = 0$ is the only valid solution over the interval $(0,1)$

And that gives you contradictions at the endpoints.

Comment: I think not the pole at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ makes the contradiction, but the fact that the $C(x_1,y_1)$ and $C(x_2,y_2)$ are not equal. Like in the case of $y(x)=C\tan(x)$, if we want $y(\pi/4)=2$ and $y(5\pi/4)=2$, it won't be a problem, even if there is a pole at $\pi/2$, but the $y(\pi/4)=2$ and $y(5\pi/4)=1$ would make some problems.